# Module exist in magento.core_resource

Tags: magento-1.9

Recently I removed a module but after removing still the module is displayed in module list and exist in magento.core_resource table , any one can help me .How I remove the module completely

Comment: please check and update me. it's works for  you ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove Magento extension manually, follow the steps below:

1- Disable the module from /app/etc/modules/.xml

set true to false

2- If their is any dependent my sql table, Remove tables.

3- In Database, Remove resource config record for the respective module from core_resource.

4- Remove the <project_root>/var/cache folder

5- Refresh you home page or any other page.

Answer (score 0):

> **To remove module completely follow below steps**

**Step:-1** Check your module status

```
bin/magento module:status
```

**Step:-2** If Check your module is enabled or not. after enabled run below command. **If your module is disabled then go to step 3**

```
bin/magento module:disable Vendorename_ModuleName
```

**Step:-3** Delete your module form /app/code directory.

**Step:-4** after run magento upgrade command

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

**Step:-5** And delete your module entry from **setup_module**

**Step:-6** At last delete your system.xml field values from **core_config_data** table

**After doing all above steps module completely removed.**